# How to declare math characters inside pandoc code block

Tags: julia, pandoc

There allows various math characters inside a Julia program. But when I tried to convert following character inside code block of my markdown file by using pandoc

```
∇
```

I got errors like

```
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ∇ in font [SourceCodePro-Regular.otf]/OT:script=
```

It seems that this problem could be solved by using a different font. I am wondering which fonts are available and how to introduce them into my markdown file.

Comment: Wha't's the exact command that you are using to generate the output? The error hints at `--pdf-engine=xelatex` being in there somewhere, but the details would be interesting.

Comment: I used following option `--pdf-engine=xelatex -V CJKmainfont="AR PL KaitiM GB" --toc --from markdown --template eisvogel --filter pandoc-crossref`

Answer (score 2):

If you are generating the PDF with XeLaTeX, which I think is the case, then you have access to all fonts installed on your system. Two popular fonts that have this character are *Fira Code* and *Noto Sans Mono*. You can make use of those fonts with pandoc by adding

```yaml
---
monofont: Fira Code
---
```

to your document's metadata, but you may have to install those first.

Comment: Much Thanks After using font "Fira Code". I still got the error  `[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ∇ in font Fira Code Regular/OT:script=latn;langu`.  Font "Noto Sans Mono" seems better. But I still got a similar error `[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ∫ in font Noto Sans Mono Regular/OT:script=latn; `.

Comment: That's weird, my Fira Code does contain that char, as does the [Fira Code on Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=%E2%88%87&preview.text_type=custom&query=fira+code). User @shayan recommended [JuliaMono](https://juliamono.netlify.app/), but unfortunately they deleted their answer.